# Pretty Print Binary Tree

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I am working on the following code challenge:

> `PrintableTree` is a simple Binary Search Tree with no balancing.
> It may contain int values that are added via the `add` method.
> The main challenge is to pretty print the tree via the `prettyPrint` method. This means that the whole tree should be converted to a String representing its inner structure from the smaller values to the greater ones. Also, you must use box-drawing characters to show node connections.
>
> #### Example:
>
> Elements: 123 11 200 1 100 150 2000
>
> Pretty printed tree:
>
> ```
>       ┌1
>    ┌11┤
>    │  └100
> 123┤
>    │   ┌150
>    └200┤
>        └2000
> ```
>
> Another example (of not so balanced tree):
>
> Elements: 931 39 196 385 388 207 185 955 957 542 904 498 394
>
> Pretty printed tree:
>
> ```
>    ┌39┐
>    │  │   ┌185
>    │  └196┤
>    │      │   ┌207
>    │      └385┤
>    │          └388┐
>    │              │       ┌394
>    │              │   ┌498┘
>    │              └542┤
>    │                  └904
> 931┤
>    └955┐
>        └957
> ```
>
> Your class should implement this interface
>
> ```
> public interface PrintableTree {
>
>     void add(int i);
>     String prettyPrint();
>
>     static PrintableTree getInstance() {
>         return new PrettyPrintableTree();
>     }
> }
> ```

I wrote this implementation:

```
public class PrettyPrintableTree implements PrintableTree {

    private static class Node {
        private final int data;
        private Node left = null;
        private Node right = null;

        public Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public int getSize() {
            return Integer.toString(data).length();
        }

    }

    private Node root = null;
    private StringBuilder mainSB = new StringBuilder();

    @Override
    public void add(int i) {
        root = add(root, i);
    }

    private Node add(Node node, int value) {
        if (node == null) {
            return new Node(value);
        } else if (value < node.data) {
            node.left = add(node.left, value);
        } else {
            node.right = add(node.right, value);
        }
        return node;
    }

    private void printSimple(Node node) {
        if (node != null) {
            printSimple(node.left);
            System.out.println(node.data);
            printSimple(node.right);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String prettyPrint() {
        printTree(root,0, false);
        System.out.println(mainSB);
        return mainSB.toString();
    }

    private void printTree(Node node, int space, boolean isRight)
    {

        if (node == null) return;

        space += node.getSize() + 1;
        printTree(node.left, space, false);

        if (node == root) {
            space = space - root.getSize() - 1;
        }
        if (node == root.left) {
            space = root.getSize();
        }
        if (node == root.right) {
            space = root.getSize();
        }

        mainSB.append(" ".repeat(Math.max(0, space)));
        if (node.right == null && node.left == null) {
            if (node == root)
                mainSB.append(node.data).append("\n");
            else
                mainSB.append(isRight ? "└" : "┌").append(node.data).append("\n");
        }
        else if (node.right != null && node.left != null) {
            if (node == root)
                mainSB.append(node.data).append("┤").append("\n");
            else
                mainSB.append(isRight ? "└" : "┌").append(node.data).append("┤").append("\n");
        }
        else if (node.right == null) {
            if (node == root)
                mainSB.append(node.data).append("┘").append("\n");
            else
                mainSB.append(isRight ? "└" : "┌").append(node.data).append("┘").append("\n");
        }
        else {
            if (node == root)
                mainSB.append(node.data).append("┐").append("\n");
            else
                mainSB.append(isRight ? "└" : "┌").append(node.data).append("┐").append("\n");
        }

        printTree(node.right, space, true);

    }
}
```

But I have some problems:

I can't figure out how to add the "|" character so to connect nodes that are far apart in their vertical distance. There are some problems with the horizontal spacing as well.

You can see these problems in the following outputs produced by the above code:

Elements: 123 11 200 1 100 150 2000

```
         ┌1
   ┌11┤
       └100
123┤
        ┌150
   └200┤
        └2000
```

elements: 931 39 196 385 388 207 185 955 957 542 904 498 394

```
   ┌39┐
           ┌185
       └196┤
               ┌207
           └385┤
               └388┐
                           ┌394
                       ┌498┘
                   └542┤
                       └904
931┤
   └955┐
       └957
```

Comment: This might be considerably easier if you would print it top down rather than  left to right.   If you are familiar with painting in Java,  painting to a `BufferedImage` and then printing that image would, imo, also be easier.  In that case you can keep objects that contain their coordinate location and then draw lines between the objects.

Comment: It might be easier to create a two-dimensional character array, fill it in with spaces, fill it with nodes, and print the array as a block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a second StringBuilder to maintain what should appear on *one* line only, so you can keep track of vertical lines that should be drawn higher up (more left) in the tree.

Then extend the main StringBuilder with copies from that.

NB: I wouldn't use an instance variable for maintaining that StringBuilder. It seems better practice to use a local variable for that, passing it on as argument.

Here are the functions you could define:

```
    public void prettyPrint() {
        System.out.println(prettyString());
    }

    public String prettyString() {
        StringBuilder treeSB = new StringBuilder();
        prettyString(root, new StringBuilder("\n"), treeSB);
        return treeSB.substring(1); // Omit initial '\n'
    }

    private void prettyString(Node node, StringBuilder lineSB, StringBuilder treeSB)
    {
        if (node == null) return;

        int dataSize = node.getSize(); // Integer.toString(node.data).length();
        int depth = lineSB.length();
        int i = "\n │".indexOf(lineSB.charAt(depth - 1));
        int j = (node.left != null ? 2 : 0) + (node.right != null ? 1 : 0);
        
        lineSB.append(" ".repeat(dataSize + 1));
        prettyString(node.left, lineSB, treeSB);
        lineSB.setLength(depth - 1);
        
        treeSB.append(lineSB);
        treeSB.append("\n┌└".charAt(i));
        treeSB.append(node.data);
        treeSB.append(" ┐┘┤".charAt(j));

        lineSB.append("\n│ ".charAt(i));
        lineSB.append(" ".repeat(dataSize));
        lineSB.append(" │ │".charAt(j));
        prettyString(node.right, lineSB, treeSB);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, I still don't fully understand all the details of the code, but it's exciting. And thanks for the tip about StringBuilder. You're awesome!