# Binary search tree printing issues

Tags: tree, binary

I have some problems with printing binary search tree. Cant find the way to implement correct number of indendations and connect nodes properly.

I am expecting this tree:

[image: Expectation]

But instead, I have this one:

[image: Reality]

Here is my code:

```java
public StringBuilder traverseInorder(StringBuilder sb, String padding, TreeNode node, String     pointer) {
    StringBuilder paddingBuilder = new StringBuilder(padding);

    int spaceCounts = Integer.toString(node.getData()).length();
    String spaces = " ".repeat(spaceCounts);

    paddingBuilder.append(spaces);
    String paddings = paddingBuilder.toString();

    if (node.getLeftNode() != null) {
      traverseInorder(sb, paddings, node.getLeftNode(), "┌");
    }
    sb.append(padding);
    sb.append(pointer);
    sb.append(node.getData());
    sb.append(getConnector(node));
    sb.append("\n");

    if (node.getRightNode() != null) {
      traverseInorder(sb, paddings, node.getRightNode(), "└");
    }

    return sb;
  }

   private String getConnector(TreeNode node) {
    String connector = "";
    if (node.getLeftNode() != null && node.getRightNode() != null) {
      connector = "┤";
    } else if (node.getLeftNode() == null && node.getRightNode() != null) {
      connector = "┐";
    } else if (node.getLeftNode() != null && node.getRightNode() == null) {
      connector = "┘";
    }
    return connector;
  }

  public String print(BinarySearchTree tree) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    return traverseInorder(sb, "", tree.getRoot(), "").toString();
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pretty Print Binary Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75686912/pretty-print-binary-tree)